# Share link on twitter from android app does not preview

Tags: android, twitter, tweets

I am trying to share an image from an *url in a tweet* via intent from my android app. The idea is that it is sharing the link but is **not previewing as card**. Can somebody give me a direction about what am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
        String mediaUrl =image;
        String description = title+" - "+author;
        String tweetUrl = String.format("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=%s&url=%s",
                urlEncode(description), urlEncode(mediaUrl));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(tweetUrl));
        filterByPackageName(this, intent, "com.twitter");
        startActivity(intent);
```

[image]

My `mediaUrl` looks like this:

https://fakeimg.pl/1200x600/?text=Opera

**but the tweet looks like this and is not showing my picture**

Comment: @Kuldeep Kulkarni : Unfortunately, I had to reject your edit. Please use `code markdown` only for code, and use **boldface** sparingly. Also, the edit removed the image. Please be more careful when editing.